# Latex Compile error with mathematical mode

Tags: math-mode

I'm trying to have the following output 
[image]

Using the following latex syntax

```
NS = \left\{t\middle|t\in{\rm tw}_{i\ }:\ t.s\ =\ -1\right\}
```

but there is an error 
any help ?!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I get no error if I complete your code this way: `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{NS} = \left\{t\middle|t\in{\rm tw}_{i\ }:\ t.s\ =\ -1\right\}
\end{equation}
\end{document}` Which error do you get?

Comment: do not use `\rm` in latex, it has not been defined by default since 1993 and is just added by some classes for compatibility with documents written before that.

Comment: sorry I tried your solution but it doesn't work,the error rise when I use my code 
NS = \left\{t\middle|t\in{\rm tw}_{i\ }:\ t.s\ =\ -1\right\}
is missing $

Comment: @Peter did you use the actual code that I posted, including `\[` (which starts math mode)? I suspect not.  Please post a complete small document as in my answer that produces the error, do not just show fragments as they can not be debugged/tested.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, using `\[` to get into math mode and avoiding manually added spaces and obsolete font commands.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[
\mathrm{NS} = \{t \mid t \in \mathrm{tw}_{i} :  t.s =-1\}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Peter the code I post above runs without error and produces the output shown. If you used `\mathrm` not in math mode then you would get the error that you state but `\[` starts math mode, as I show above.

Comment: I copy same code of yours and use it but doesn't work, there is somthing strange happen that before my code was working well but now when I wanted to edit the file I met this error, now using my code 
NS = \left\{t\middle|t\in{\rm tw}_{i\ }:\ t.s\ =\ -1\right\}
rise the error of missing $

Comment: @Peter  stop showing fragments!!! in all the fragments that you have shown you have not once shown any code that starts math mode, so clearly any math mode command will give an error.

Comment: @Peter also as I have said `\rm` is wrong and you want `\mid` here not `|` and do not want `\left`..`right` you seem to just be re-using the code from the question, completely ignoring the answer?

Comment: Sorry it could problem in defining the problem, I need to show only the equation that I've mentioned in the post of question regardless if it done my math mode or not
thank you

Comment: @Peter tex has a strong division between text and math, if you use (any) math commands without entering math mode you will get an error, without redesigning tex you can not just "want" things to work the same way in math mode or text mode, that is not how tex works. You need to enter math mode to typeset math.

Comment: Now it works Thanks a lot

Comment: @Peter since I have not edited the answer presumably it always worked, please delete the comments stating otherwise, thanks.